# Powershell - Syntax error - pasting string from a function into "-Filter"

Tags: string, function, variables, powershell

Here is my code:
I try to build a filter string in a function and us it in and get-adobject command,
but I get an syntax error an position 1

```
function build-filter ([string]$searchName)
{
$searchName = '"' + $searchName + '"'
$searchName = "{name -like " + $searchName + "}"
return [string]$searchName
}

$searchname = "user1"

$filter = build-filter $searchname

Get-ADObject -Filter $filter
```

This is the Error message, unfortunatelly in German

> Get-ADObject : Fehler beim Analysieren der Abfrage: "{name -like "user1"}" Fehlermeldung: "syntax error" 
>   an folgender Position: "1".
>   In Zeile:12 Zeichen:1
>   + Get-ADObject -Filter $filter
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADObject], ADFilterParsingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingEx 
>      ception,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADObject

what am I doing wrong here?
do I missunderstand some concept?

Comment: It may help if you translate the error message. Even though I studied German at school, it's far from enough to understand the above.

Comment: Try this `$searchName = "{name -like $searchName }"`

Comment: unfortunatelly this didnt work. but leaving out the curly bracets helps as suggested by C.B.
thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing this:

```
$searchName = "{name -like " + $searchName + "}"
```

in

```
$searchName = "name -like $searchName"
```

Comment: the seccond suggestion works: $searchName = "name -like $searchName"
 I guess the "{" is the one producing the error.